# Backspacing through multiple entry widgets/validation issues

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I had some success trying entry widget validation for the first time. However, upon trying to more precisely define the callback function, I encountered an issue. The initial validation I wanted was to limit the number of characters and then set the focus to the next entry widget once that limit was reached. I was able to do this successfully; but, when I went back and added a while loop to try and further limit the entry widgets to digits only, the while loop did not work. Why does the while loop not apply? Is there another way to accomplish this numbers-only validation with the current callback function(s)?

```
import random
import string
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('325x75+750+350')
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)
window.title('Phone Number Test')

var=tk.StringVar(window,'')

def entrycheckone(inp):
   while inp.isdigit:
    if len(inp) == 3:
        entry2.focus_set()
        return True
    elif len(inp)<3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def entrychecktwo(inp):
    if len(inp) == 3:
        entry3.focus_set()
        return True
    elif len(inp) < 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def entrycheckthree(inp):
    if len(inp) == 4:
        entry3.focus_set()
        return True
    elif len(inp) < 4:
        return True
    else:
        return False

label1=tk.Label(text='Enter Phone Number(XXX-XXX-XXXX):', font='arial 10 bold')
label1.place(anchor='nw', x=38, y=3)

entry1=tk.Entry(width=3, font='arial 10 bold')
entry1.place(anchor='nw', x=3, y=30)
entry1.focus_set()

max1 = window.register(entrycheckone)
entry1.config(validate='key', validatecommand=(max1,'%P'))


label2=tk.Label(text='-', font='arial 20')
label2.place(anchor='nw', x=30, y=19)

entry2=tk.Entry(width=3, font='arial 10 bold')
entry2.place(anchor='nw', x=47, y=30)

max2 = window.register(entrychecktwo)
entry2.config(validate='key', validatecommand=(max2,'%P'))


label3=tk.Label(text='-', font='arial 20')
label3.place(anchor='nw', x=73, y=19)

entry3=tk.Entry(width=4, font='arial 10 bold')
entry3.place(anchor='nw', x=90, y=30)

max3 = window.register(entrycheckthree)
entry3.config(validate='key',validatecommand=(max3, '%P'))


display1=tk.Entry(width=13, textvariable=var, font='arial 10 bold',state='disabled')
display1.place(anchor='nw', x=200, y=30)

def setphone():
    num1 = entry1.get()
    num2 = entry2.get()
    num3 = entry3.get()
    wholenum = ('(' + num1 + ')-' + num2 + '-' + num3)
    print(wholenum)
    var.set(wholenum)


button1=tk.Button(text='ENTER', font='arial 10 bold', command=setphone)
button1.place(anchor='nw', x=130, y=26)



window.mainloop()
```

As an aside, what method do ya'll use to add in those 4 extra spaces to your expansive codes when you post them here? I just spent a full 2 minutes putting those spaces in, but I Know there's got to be an obvious, easier method I'm overlooking. LOL

My second question is, now that I've created this code that uses focus_set to move to each next Entry widget, I want to use the backspace key to do the exact opposite, moving the focus to the right side of the previous widget until each is emptied. Any advice on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the while loop isn't working? It's working, it's just not doing what you think. Since `inp` never changes, the loop has no way to exit.

Comment: _"As an aside, what method do ya'll use to add in those 4 extra spaces to your expansive codes when you post them here?"_ - there's a button that looks like `{}`. Select all of your code and then click that button.

Comment: @BryanOakley, ended up using try/except and that solved my problem.